# Raw Pointer Management in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I have a piece of performance critical code. The class and objects are fairly large, hence, it would be stored as pointers in the STL container. Problems arise when the pointers to objects need to be stored in multiple different containers based on some logic. It is very messy in handling the ownership of the object as I couldn't isolate the ownership of the object to a single containers(which I could just delete from the single container). Other than using smart pointer (since it is performance critical and smart pointer might affects the performance), what could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the smart pointer. Profile to check if it does have too much impact. Chances are, it won't be too much, and it's likely to be less than most roll-your-own solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much you can do. You need to define responsibilities, i.e. who is responsible for owning your resources. This is, in my opinion, a fundamental problem with C++ and probably one of the biggest reasons people are moving to other languages.

Comment: Did you *profiled* the smart pointer or is it just your guess?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking for impossible - from one point, you are asking for exceptional performance, such that smart pointers you claim cannot provide, and you also happen to ask for safety and tidiness. Well, one comes at the cost of another, actually. You could, of course try to write your own shared pointer, which would be more lightweight than boost's, but still provide the basic functionality. Incidentally, have you actually *tried* boost::shared_ptr? Did it *actually* slow down the performance?

Comment: One point about `shared_ptr`: best use `make_shared` to build it, it's much more efficient.

Comment: Also, you can disable shared_ptr's thread safety to avoid paying the cost of mutexes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very awkward: you ask for performance with a messy logic ?

`shared_ptr` have incredible performance, really, and though you can get better it is probably your best choice: it works.

You could look up another Boost smart pointer though: [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html).

This is done at the cost of foregoing: `weak_ptr` and in exchange allows to have a single memory allocation for both the counter and the object. Packing up the two yields a SMALL increase in performance.

If you do not have cyclic reference, try and check it out, it might be what you were looking for.

Comment: The packing can be achieved with make_shared function as well.

Comment: @ronag: if I remember correctly `make_shared` still does 2 allocations, because the `counter` is shared between the `shared_ptr` pool and the `weak_ptr` pool and lives a life on its own. What `make_shared` packs is the deleter and the actual allocated object. I can be mistaken though, trudging through boost source is certainly not my favorite past-time.

Answer (score 0):

Intrusive smart pointers are typically more efficient than normal smart pointers, yet easier than dumb pointers. For instance, check out `boost::intrusive_ptr<T>`

Answer (score 0):

If the objects don't refer to one another, manual reference counting might be worth trying. There would be more cost when adding to or removing from a list, but no overhead to the actual object access. (This can be painful to diagnose when you get it wrong, so I recommend being careful to get it right.)

If there is dead time between operations, consider a sort of garbage collect. Maintain the list of all objects (an intrusive list would probably do). When you have time to spare, cross-reference this against the other lists; any objects that aren't in a list can get deleted. You don't need an extra array to do this (just a global counter and a last-seen counter on each object) so it could be reasonably efficient.

Another option would be to use a smart pointer that provides access to the underlying pointer. If you're trying to avoid the overhead of calling an overloaded `operator->` a lot then this might be worth trying. Store the smart pointers in the lists (this does the lifetime management for you) and then when running through the objects you can retrieve the raw pointer for each and operate using that (so you don't incur the overhead of any overloaded `operator->` etc.). For example:

```
std::vector<smart_ptr<T> > objects;

if(!objects.empty()) {
    smart_ptr<T> *objects_raw=&objects[0];
    for(size_t n=objects.size(),i=0;i<n;++i) {
        T *object=objects_raw[i].get_ptr();

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This is the sort of approach I prefer personally. Long-term storage gets a smart pointer, short-term storage gets a plain pointer. The object lifetimes are easy to manage, and you don't fall foul of 1,000,000 tiny overheads (more important for keeping the debug build runnable than it is for the release build, but it can easily add to wasted time nonetheless).